# Dataform reuse table confing in javascript

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-platform, dataform, google-dataform

Is it possible to reuse configurations defined in table config in a post operation in dataform?

For example what I am trying to accomplish is using config.uniqueKeys in the post operation function

```
config {
    type: "table",
    schema: "test",
    tags: ["test"],
    uniqueKey: ["KEY_VALUE"]
}

post_operations {
    ${file.function(config.uniqueKey)}
}
```

at the moment I duplicate definition of unique keys `${file.function(["KEY_VALUE"])}`

Thanks